# Qt fixed-width font

Tags: qt, font-size

I need to restrict a custom widget `setFont()` so that it only accepts fixed-width fonts.

However, I can’t find how to programmatically define whether a particular `QFont` is a fixed-width one. Is there such a possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps **[`bool QFontInfo::fixedPitch()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfontinfo.html#fixedPitch)** is the function you are looking for:

```
void MyWidet::setFont ( const QFont& font )
{
    QFontInfo fontInfo(font);
    if(fontInfo.fixedPitch())
        QWidget::setFont(font);

    // Otherwise ignore..
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ammar. What makes me a bit confused is that `QFontInfo::fixedPitch()` docs contain `QFont::fixedPitch()` in *see also* section, but `QFont` also has `setFixedPitch()` method. That is, *fixed pitch* can be *set* on the font… Sounds pretty strange.

Comment: @DmitrySavchenko: `QFontInfo` is more reliable than `QFont`. As per documentation, `QFont` access functions return the values that were set, while `QFontInfo` object returns the values that apply to the font (system installed font) that will actually be used to draw the text. So even if you call `font->setFixedPitch(true)`, it will match that font to actual system font and then will draw it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. All I need is `QFontInfo` to be reliable regardless `QFont::setFixedPitch(true)` was called by someone or not. Seems to be so.

Answer (score 0):

Add `YourWidget->setStylesheet("QWidget{font: 10pt "Ubuntu";}");`

This way you can restrict your widget size to 10pt and font of type Ubuntu unless you change it elsewhere Programmatically.