# Default fixed-width font in Qt

Tags: qt, fonts

Is there a cross-platform way of getting the user's preferred fixed-width and proportional fonts in Qt?

For example, in Cocoa, there is

```
NSFont *proportional = [NSFont userFontOfSize:12.0f];
NSFont *fixed_width = [NSFont userFixedPitchFontOfSize:12.0f];
```

I would like to find an equivalent in Qt that works in Mac, Linux, and Windows.

Comment: I think these should help:

[Specify font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468022/how-to-specify-monospace-fonts-for-cross-platform-qt-applications) 
and 
[Check if fixed width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977259/qt-fixed-width-font)

Comment: @Matthew: almost.  They will get a fixed font, but not the system default.  For example, on my Mac, the default fixed font is Monaco, but using `QFont font("Monospace"); font.setStyleHint(QFont::TypeWriter);` gets me Courier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using QFontDatabase's systemFont(..) function, you can retrieve

- the system's default font
- the **default fixed font**
- the "title" font
- the smallest readable font

Example:

```
const QFont fixedFont = QFontDatabase::systemFont(QFontDatabase::FixedFont)
```

Introduced in Qt 5.2